# How do I fix OpenSSL SSL_read: error ssl3_get_record:decryption failed or bad record mac?

Tags: node.js, linux

I have installed a wsl and I'm having some ssl3 issues when trying to install nvm. I have read through and tried some of the fixes for the same types of errors in different threads. I believe this is an issue with the hashmap and checksum and how it is setup on my machine. Error code below. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
nvm install 14.16.1

Downloading and installing node v14.16.1...

Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v14.16.1/node-v14.16.1-linux-x64.tar.xz...
#################################                                                                                  29.3%curl: (56) OpenSSL SSL_read: error:1408F119:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:decryption failed or bad record mac, errno 0

Binary download from https://nodejs.org/dist/v14.16.1/node-v14.16.1-linux-x64.tar.xz failed, trying source.
grep: /home/username/.nvm/.cache/bin/node-v14.16.1-linux-x64/node-v14.16.1-linux-x64.tar.xz: No such file or directory
Provided file to checksum does not exist.
Binary download failed, trying source.
Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v14.16.1/node-v14.16.1.tar.xz...
############                                                                                                       10.8%curl: (56) OpenSSL SSL_read: error:1408F119:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:decryption failed or bad record mac, errno 0

Binary download from https://nodejs.org/dist/v14.16.1/node-v14.16.1.tar.xz failed, trying source.
grep: /home/username/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v14.16.1/node-v14.16.1.tar.xz: No such file or directory
Provided file to checksum does not exist.
```

Comment: Have you found nay solution?